# Correct JSDoc syntax for nullable return type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

With Javascript function JSDocs, I've seen two different syntaxes for documenting the return values that can be nullable.

Let's say we have this function:

```
const getTitle = () => { // Can return string or null };
```

For this, which of the following JSDocs is correct:

1. @returns {?string}
2. @returns [string]
3. Something else?

Comment: I wrote this [cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/5206dcb44670e34f6923b62c1781e1d2) to help me with this. Sharing in case it's useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, the first preferred:

```
@returns {?string}
```

```
@returns {string|null}
```